# How to select only the records having timestamp of sunday

Tags: mysql

How to  select the records which i inserted only in **Sunday**. My file having timestamp date type. I have the following query                                                                   SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE  DAYNAME(created_tstamp)='sunday'. Is there any other sql functions for better performance?.

Comment: I have the following query..                                              SELECT *
FROM travel_booking
WHERE DATE(created_tstamp) >= '2013-11-02'
    AND DATE(created_tstamp) <= '2014-02-01' AND DAYNAME(created_tstamp)='sunday';  Is there any better than this issue?

Comment: I've got several ideas. Do you have any?

Comment: I think this link will help you mysql 'week' fundion   http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php

Comment: @dimancrown What you posted as a comment should go in the question. Also try the answers provided and add feedback or approve if they work for you.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one

```
SELECT * from table where DAYNAME( DATE( timestamp ) )="sunday"
```

or your query

```
SELECT * FROM travel_booking WHERE DATE(created_tstamp) >= '2013-11-02' AND DATE(created_tstamp) <= '2014-02-01' AND DAYNAME( DATE( timestamp ) )='sunday';
```

This will help you

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `DAYOFWEEK()`, from the [Date and Time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) MySQL functions as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
    travel_booking
WHERE
    DATE(created_tstamp) >= '2013-11-02' AND
    DATE(created_tstamp) <= '2014-02-01' AND
    DAYOFWEEK(created_tstamp) = 1;
```

Documentation:

> **DAYOFWEEK(date)**
>
> Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.

Comment: Thanks chevi. I got the output.